# circularly layout smaller squares within a large square

Tags: html, canvas, graphics

Given a bounding square and the total number of smaller squares. The smaller squares need to be drawn within the bigger square evenly spaced out in a circular fashion, just touching but not overlapping. How do you compute the width of the inner square ?

*(updated fiddle link)*
http://jsfiddle.net/mdluffy/6bUVz/3/

```
///////// INPUTS ///////////////////////////////////////////
var BoundingBoxSide = 100;
var NofInnerBoxes = 14; 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
 drawBoxes();

function drawBoxes()
{
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(0,0,BoundingBoxSide,BoundingBoxSide);
ctx.stroke();

for(var i=0; i < NofInnerBoxes; i++)
{
    // ************************************************************************************ //
    // This needs to be computed so that the boxes touch each other, but not overlap
    var innerBoxSide = 20;   
    // ************************************************************************************ //
    var angle = degToRad(i * 360/NofInnerBoxes);
    var innerX = ((BoundingBoxSide - innerBoxSide)/2) * Math.cos(angle);
    var innerY = ((BoundingBoxSide - innerBoxSide)/2) * Math.sin(angle);
    ctx.rect(BoundingBoxSide/2 + innerX - innerBoxSide/2, BoundingBoxSide/2 - innerY - innerBoxSide/2, innerBoxSide, innerBoxSide);

    ctx.stroke();

}
}

function degToRad(d)
{
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Update:

I'm working on a 3D visualization using Three.js. This is a tree structure with nodes represented as cubes. The child node cubes are layed out circularly on top of the parent node cubes. Applied recursively.

The inner squares need not touch the outer squares, but it should touch the largest circle that can be fit inside the outer square.

Comment: Your fiddle link is empty. Is this for optimizing packaging?

Comment: You showed what code you tried; what does it do and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: Clarifying question: must the inner squares touch the outer square on all four sides? I don't think so... because such a snug rectangle often wouldn't be square.

Comment: @LarsH for the first question: compute innerBoxSide instead of hard coding.

Comment: How about if the inner squares are not necessarily touching each other, but their circumscribed circles are touching?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and let me know whether it meets your requirements (up/downvote, comment, and/or Accept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
var alpha = Math.PI * (NofInnerBoxes - 2) / (2 * NofInnerBoxes)
var t = Math.tan(alpha)
var innerBoxSide = BoundingBoxSide / Math.sqrt(t*t + 4*t + 5)
```

(Credit: to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28r/2%29%5E2%20=%20%28s/2%29%5E2%20%2b%20%28s%20%281%20%2b%20t/2%29%29%5E2,%20t%20=%20tan%28pi/2%20-%20pi/n%29,%20solve%20for%20s) for solving for `innerBoxSide`; and to an envelope I doodled on the back of.)

**Update:** The above was under the assumption that two sides of each inner square are parallel to a line that passes through the centers of that inner square and the outer square. I now see that this assumption was not what you had in mind.

Here's another approach. In this one, the circles that circumscribe the inner squares will all touch each other, though the inner squares themselves will not quite touch each other:

```
var alpha = Math.PI / NofInnerBoxes
var t = Math.sin(alpha)
var innerBoxSide = BoundingBoxSide * t / ((t + 1) * Math.sqrt(2))
```

Result:

[image]

## Derivation

In response to the request for how the formula was derived...

Let *r_s* (r sub s) be the "small radius", i.e. the radius of the circles that circumscribe the inner squares. These inner circles are all tangent to the big circle that **in**scribes the outer square. Call the radius of the big circle r_b (b for "big").

Note that the side of the outer square, a.k.a. BoundingBoxSide, is = 2 * r_b. Note also that the diameter of each inner circle, 2 * r_s, is also the diagonal of each inner square. Therefore the *side* of each inner square, a.k.a. innerBoxSide, is = (2 * r_s) / sqrt(2).

Now let angle *alpha* = half the angle that each inner circle subtends (if that's the right verb) around the center of the big circle. I.e. alpha = (2 * pi / NofInnerBoxes) / 2 = pi / NofInnerBoxes.

The key is to draw a right triangle, where one of the angles is alpha; this will tell us the ratios between all the sides of that triangle, using trig functions like `sin()`. And we can draw such a triangle whose vertices are:

```
A. The center of the big circle
B. The center of a small circle
C. The point where that small circle touches its neighbor
```

The right angle is at vertex C, and the angle alpha is at vertex A. The length of side BC = r_s, and the length of the hypotenuse (AB) = r_b - r_s.

So by the definition of sin(), we can say that sin(alpha) = opposite side / hypotenuse = BC / AB = r_s / (r_b - r_s). Solve this equation for r_s, and we get r_s = r_b * sin(alpha) / (1 + sin(alpha)).

Finally, plug in the fact (above) that BoundingBoxSide = 2 * r_b, and innerBoxSide = (2 * r_s) / sqrt(2); and you get the formula shown above, `innerBoxSide = BoundingBoxSide * t / ((t + 1) * Math.sqrt(2))`.

Sorry this is a longish wall of text, but I hope it's sufficiently clear if read carefully. I may post a diagram as well, if time allows. Let me know if you have questions. (There's probably an easier way to derive this, but that's how I did it.)

Comment: @OP: Hmm... now that you updated your fiddle link, I see that you want all the inner boxes to be oriented the same way. I was picturing the inner boxes being rotated around the edges of the circle. So if the above answer isn't acceptable for your purpose, let me know. That seems harder than the question I thot you were asking.

Comment: @OP: I just posted an update. It works for me. See what you think.

Comment: thanks LarsH. I'd really appreciate if you explained how you arrived at the equation.

Comment: @MDLuffy: drawings on the back of an envelope again. I drew a diagram for the case where NofInnerBoxes==5, so we had 5 circles touching... then started drawing lines between the points I could see, and looking for relationships between sides and angles of right triangles. When I get to the office tomorrow I'll try and look for the envelope. But as you probably know, sin(a) = length of opposite side / hypotenuse. And sqrt(2) is the ratio of the side of the inner square to the diameter of its circumscribed circle.

Comment: @MDLuffy: I updated my answer with an explanation of how I derived the formula.